# Why is classical probability calculated the way it is?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am eager to know what was the intuition behind creating formula for discrete probability

$$P(E) = \frac{\lvert E \rvert}{\lvert S \rvert}$$

Where $E$ is the set of event we want to calculated the probability of, and $S$ is the set of all possible outcomes (i.e sample space).

Also, this could mean I have problem understanding fractions (like why to put this number in denominator or numerator).

Comment: Imagine rolling a 20 sided die repeatedly. What fraction of the time will you roll a multiple of three?

Comment: For this to work,  you need each event (perhaps element of the sample space) being counted in the numerator and denominator to be of equal probability

Comment: If we were to assume any two atomic outcomes occur with the same probability... that is $P(\{x\})=P(\{y\})$ (*i.e. it is an "equiprobable sample space"*), and that the sample space is finite, it follows from additivity and other definitions of probability that $1 = \Pr(S)=\Pr(\bigcup\limits_{x\in S} \{x\})=\sum\limits_{x\in S}\Pr(\{x\}) = |S|\Pr(\{x\})$ and so $\Pr(\{x\})=\frac{1}{|S|}$.  Similarly, $\Pr(E) = \Pr(\bigcup\limits_{x\in E}\{x\})=\sum\limits_{x\in E}\Pr(\{x\}) = |E|\cdot\frac{1}{|S|}$

Comment: In more layman's terms... we need the probabilities to add up to one for each outcome that could happen, so each outcome happens some fraction of time proportional to the number of outcomes possible.

Comment: Here is what I think, generally, if any thing as more frequency, and we blindly select it (like picking balls from urn), then its "chances" would be more than other objects. For example, let's say we have 10 balls, out of which 7 are black and 3 are white. Now changes are most of the time we will pick black ball. Now  like @drhab mentioned, their probability should sum to 1 (also an axiom), we need to map this output to fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an intuitive answer: if $S$ is a set containing all your possible outcomes, and all outcomes are equally as likely, then this means each ${s \in S}$ has a ${1/|S|}$ chance of occurring. If you are considering a subset of special events of interest ${E\subseteq S}$, then precisely ${|E|/|S|}$ is the ratio of special events to all events. So the chance of picking an ${s}$ which belongs to the subset $E$ is precisely ${|E|/|S|}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz true. I have removed the bit about independence

Comment: The outcomes must not be presented as independent but as mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ denote a non-empty and finite set of outcomes and let it be that these outcomes are equiprobable.

For every $s\in S$, where  let $E_s$ denote the event that outcome $s$ will show up such that $E_s \in \mathcal{P} (S)$

(Actually we could also write $\{s\}$ instead of $E_s$)

Then because it is for sure that exactly one outcome will show up:$$\sum_{s\in S}P(E_s)=1\tag1$$Moreover because the outcomes are equiprobable we have:$$P(E_s)\text{ does not depend on }s\tag2$$Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude that:$$P(E_s)=\frac1{|S|}\text{ for every }s\in S$$

Now if $E\subseteq S$ then the probability that an element of $E$ shows up as outcome is:$$P\left(\bigcup_{s\in E}E_s\right)=\sum_{s\in E}P(E_s)=\frac{|E|}{|S|}$$